# Starting a SQL server on fedora

Tags: fedora, database, sql-server, sql

I am a total databases noob, hence please be gentle.

I am looking for tutorials how to create a SQL table, how to start a SQL server, and what software to use on fedora. Would anyone share links to good tutorials?

Also, what software should I use to create SQL table and to start the server? I am on fedora 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few popular SQL database management systems shipped with Fedora. Here are some how-tos for the most popular:

MySQL:
http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-fedora9
(skip to the MySQL part)

PostgreSQL:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-fedora-linux-install-postgresql-server/

After you have installed the software, you can create your databases manually using the shell (each database system ships with a set of commands which allow running SQL statements), or you can install a web-based tool. These show the structure of your databases graphically.

For MySQL: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

For PostgreSQL: http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/

I should also point out that in order to create a table you need to create database to contain it. Take a look at [SQLzoo](http://sqlzoo.net/) for a basic introduction into how it works.